# laravel Image previewd as thumbail only in view but in source page the link to storage is right

Tags: laravel, image

while i view the source page of that code it shows the correct link to that image and when i click that it shows the actual image but not shows in the views of admin panel
[web view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc45s.png)

[post controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fQA9.png)

[view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIss9.png)

if u want to see the code please visit the code in github:https://github.com/itsmebiky/ads_nepal.git
its in the postcontroller controller where the image is uploaded in the db and view.backend.viewpost.blade.php and vie.backend.createview.blade.php are the file to look.. thanks you

Comment: Please [edit] your post and paste the view and controller *as text*. Images do not help us debug your code.

Comment: Hi Bi Ka Sh. Welcome to SO. Please include code as real code,  [**not as an image**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) if possible. Please include the HTML and CSS you're using, in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use the [**Stack Snippets**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) feature to help you out.

Comment: Did you read the above comments?

Answer (score 0):

Try in the blade with: 
`<img src='{{ asset('ads_image/'.$post->ads_image) }}'>`

Comment: now with this in the blade it is not showing the thumbnail also

Comment: edit the controller: 
`$path = $request->file('ads_image')->storeAs('public/ads_image/',$fileNameToStore);`

Answer (score 0):

I have cloned your repository and take a look into your code the problem is you are uploading the images in `storage_path` not `public_path`

you can read the difference here

[Laravel Storage Path](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-storage-path)

[Laravel Public Path](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-public-path)

To get files uploaded in `storage_path` you need to make a route in your `web.php`

```
Route::get('view/{image}', function ($image) {
    $path = storage_path('app/public/ads_image/').$image;

    $file = \File::get($path);
    $type = \File::mimeType($path);

    $response = \Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
})->name('image.view');
```

in your `viewpost.blade.php` in image source you will call the route instead of asset and pass to it the image name from your eloquent

```
<img src='{{ route('image.view', $post->ads_image) }}'>
```